# Compiling in using android NDK fails

Tags: android

I was trying to compile Magisk in android studio and it had told me to use the build.py file to build the binarys and so I did.
Except I get this error ALL THE TIME!

- Building binaries: magisk magiskinit magiskboot busybox
  fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
  C:/Users/(name)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/magisk/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:654: Android NDK: Module magisk depends on undefined modules: cxx

Anyway to fix this?
I did install Cmake for windows and I still can't figure out what cxx might be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Magisk GitHub repository is, in fact, multiple repositories composed. To download all of them you need to:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk.git
```

This is mentioned in the readme.md as well as on the GitHub main page: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk